# How can I setup git to checkout some files crlf, others lf?

Tags: git, line-endings

I have a git repository which contains (among others) `*.wse` text files and `*.sh` text files. How can I setup git to always checkout `*.wse` files with `CRLF` line endings and `*.sh` files with `LF` line endings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file to specify e.g.

```
*.wse eol=crlf
*.sh eol=lf
```